# How to avoid double plot with multiple inputs Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a shiny app where changes to the pickerInputs update a set of plots. These inputs are time, zone or dimension filters and also indicators. The indicators do not have to have the same time period.

Unfortunately, there are situations where changing the indicator (ind_1) causes a chart to be redrawn. Then refresh again and the graph is drawn a second time. So I end up with a plot redraw multiple times.

I want that when a user changes the year, the zone or a dimension the drawing is updated. But when the user changes indicators, he can also end up updating the whole drawing at the same time and not in two parts.

Is there a way to allow a short delay, so that shiny "updates" and doesn't have the inputs trigger the plot?

[image: Example of double plot]

Here is part of my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS)
library(plotly)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(googledrive)

id1 <- "1Gc9M9mN0U38QXobrFBgdTNYFdCTCU0GZ"
id<-"1cZRfzycJ-bhXHEAC_2g6b6sbOhInlmMG"
metadatos<-read.csv2(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id1),
                     encoding = "UTF-8")
metadatos<-subset(metadatos,metadatos[,1]!="")
indicadores<-read.csv2(sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", id),
                       encoding = "UTF-8")
indicadores<-subset(indicadores,indicadores[,1]!="")
indicadores_id<-data.frame(cbind(substr(colnames(indicadores[4:length(indicadores)]),3,100),
                                 4:length(indicadores)))
names(indicadores_id)<-c("ID","column")
metadatos<-subset(metadatos,metadatos[,4] %in% indicadores_id[,1])


list_ind_factor_1<-unique(metadatos[,1])
list_ind_factor_1<-list_ind_factor_1[list_ind_factor_1!=""]
list_ind_factor_2<-unique(metadatos[,2])
list_ind_factor_2<-list_ind_factor_2[list_ind_factor_2!=""]
list_ind<-unique(metadatos$NOMBRE)
list_zona<-unique(indicadores$CCAA)
list_dim<-unique(indicadores$Sexo)

simpleCap <- function(x) {
  s <- strsplit(x, " ")[[1]]
  paste(toupper(substring(s, 1,1)), substring(s, 2),
        sep="", collapse=" ")
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$ind_1, {
    output$ft_1<-renderText({
      if(isTRUE(input$ft_ind_1)){
        m<-1
      } else {
        m<-0
      }
      m
    })
    outputOptions(output, 'ft_1', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
    output$titol_1<-renderText({
      m<-subset(metadatos,metadatos[,5]==input$ind_1)
      if (nrow(m)!=0){
        m<-m[,5]
      } else {
        m<-"NO"
      }
      m
    })
    output$det_1<-renderText({
      m<-subset(metadatos,metadatos[,5]==input$ind_1)
      if (nrow(m)!=0){
        m<-m[,3]
      } else {
        m<-"NO"
      }
      m
    })
    output$unit_1<-renderText({
      m<-subset(metadatos,metadatos[,5]==input$ind_1)
      if (nrow(m)!=0){
        m<-m[,6]
      } else {
        m<-"NO"
      }
      m
    })
    output$serie_1<-renderText({
      m<-subset(metadatos,metadatos[,5]==input$ind_1)
      ind<-subset(indicadores_id,indicadores_id[,1]==m[,4])
      n<-data.frame(indicadores[,1],
                    indicadores[,as.numeric(ind[,2])])
      n<-n[!is.na(n[,2]), ]
      if (nrow(n)!=0){
        k<-paste(min(n[,1]),max(n[,1]),sep="-")
      } else {
        k<-paste("-")
      }
      k
    })
    output$titol_<-renderText({
      m<-subset(metadatos,metadatos[,5]==input$ind_1)
      if (nrow(m)==0){
        m<-0
      } else {
        m<-1
      }
      m
    })
    outputOptions(output, 'titol_', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  }, ignoreInit = F, ignoreNULL = F)
  observeEvent(c(input$ind_1_factor_1,input$ind_1_factor_2,input$ind_1), {
    if(length(input$ind_1_factor_1)!=0){
      m<-subset(metadatos, metadatos[,1] %in% input$ind_1_factor_1)
    } else {
      m<-metadatos
    }
    if(length(input$ind_1_factor_2)!=0){
      n<-subset(metadatos, metadatos[,2] %in% input$ind_1_factor_2)
    } else {
      n<-metadatos
    }
    if(length(input$ind_1)!=0){
      a<-subset(metadatos, metadatos[,5] %in% input$ind_1)
      if (nrow(a)!=0){
        a_id<-subset(indicadores_id,indicadores_id[,1]==a[,4])
        a_id<-data.frame(indicadores[,1],
                         indicadores[,2],
                         indicadores[,3],
                         indicadores[,as.numeric(a_id[,2])])
        names(a_id)<-c("year","dim","zona","valor")
        a_id<-a_id[!is.na(a_id$valor),]
        a_id<-subset(a_id,valor!="")
        a_id_<-subset(a_id,zona!="ESPAÑA")
        a_id <- a_id[order(a_id$year,decreasing = T),]
        updatePickerInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "ind_1_any_1",
                          label = "Selecciona el periodo a estudiar:",
                          choices = unique(a_id_$year),
                          selected = unique(a_id_$year))
        if(is.null(input$ind_1_zona_1)){
          updatePickerInput(session = session,
                            inputId = "ind_1_zona_1",
                            label = "Selecciona las zonas a estudiar:",
                            choices = unique(a_id$zona),
                            selected = c("ESPAÑA"))
        } else {
          updatePickerInput(session = session,
                            inputId = "ind_1_zona_1",
                            label = "Selecciona las zonas a estudiar:",
                            choices = unique(a_id$zona),
                            selected = input$ind_1_zona_1)
        }
        if(a_id$dim %in% "Ambos sexos"){
          updatePickerInput(session = session,
                            inputId = "ind_1_dim_1",
                            label = "Selecciona el sexo a estudiar:",
                            choices = unique(a_id$dim),
                            selected = c("Ambos sexos"))
          updatePickerInput(session = session,
                            inputId = "ind_1_dim_11",
                            label = "Sexo a estudiar:",
                            choices = unique(a_id$dim),
                            selected = c("Ambos sexos"))
          updatePickerInput(session = session,
                            inputId = "ind_1_dim_12",
                            label = "Sexo a estudiar:",
                            choices = unique(a_id$dim),
                            selected = c("Ambos sexos"))
        } else {
          updatePickerInput(session = session,
                            inputId = "ind_1_dim_1",
                            label = "Selecciona el sexo a estudiar:",
                            choices = unique(a_id$dim),
                            selected = unique(a_id$dim))
          updatePickerInput(session = session,
                            inputId = "ind_1_dim_11",
                            label = "Sexo a estudiar:",
                            choices = unique(a_id$dim),
                            selected = unique(a_id$dim))
          updatePickerInput(session = session,
                            inputId = "ind_1_dim_12",
                            label = "PENE:",
                            choices = unique(a_id$dim),
                            selected = unique(a_id$dim))
        }
        updatePickerInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "ind_1_any_11",
                          label = "Periodos a estudiar:",
                          choices = unique(a_id$year),
                          selected = unique(a_id$year))
        updatePickerInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "ind_1_any_12",
                          label = "Periodo a estudiar:",
                          choices = unique(a_id$year),
                          selected = unique(a_id$year))
        updatePickerInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "ind_1_zona_11",
                          label = "Zonas a estudiar:",
                          choices = unique(a_id$zona),
                          selected = unique(a_id$zona))
        updatePickerInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "ind_1_zona_12",
                          label = "Zonas a estudiar:",
                          choices = unique(a_id$zona),
                          selected = unique(a_id$zona))
      }
    } else {
      a<-metadatos
    }
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "ind_1_factor_2",
                      label = "Filtra por el factor de desigualdad: ",
                      choices = unique(m[,2]),
                      selected = input$ind_1_factor_2)
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "ind_1",
                      label = "Elige un indicador:",
                      choices = unique(n[,5]),
                      selected = input$ind_1)
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "ind_2",
                      label = "Elige un indicador:",
                      choices = unique(n[,5]),
                      selected = input$ind_1)
    updatePickerInput(session = session,
                      inputId = "ind_3",
                      label = "Elige un indicador:",
                      choices = unique(n[,5]),
                      selected = input$ind_1)
  }, ignoreInit = F, ignoreNULL = F)
  observeEvent(c(input$ind_1,input$ind_1_zona_1,input$ind_1_dim_1,input$ind_1_any_1),{
    ############# FER 3 FILTRES DIFERENTS PER CADA PLOT #############
    output$dots_box<-renderPlotly({
      a_<-subset(metadatos, metadatos[,5] %in% input$ind_1)
      a_id<-subset(indicadores_id,indicadores_id[,1]==a_[,4])
      a_id<-data.frame(indicadores[,1],
                       indicadores[,2],
                       indicadores[,3],
                       as.numeric(indicadores[,as.numeric(a_id[,2])]),
                       a_[,6])
      names(a_id)<-c("Periodo","Sexo","Zonas","Valor","Dim")
      a_id<-subset(a_id,!is.na(Valor))
      n<-input$ind_1
      a<-subset(a_id,a_id[,2] %in% input$ind_1_dim_1)
      a<-subset(a,a[,1] %in% input$ind_1_any_1)
      b<-subset(a,a[,3]!="ESPAÑA")
      a<-subset(a,a[,3] %in% input$ind_1_zona_1)
      if (length(unique(a[,2]))>2){
        sex<-tolower(paste(unique(a[,2])[1]," , ",unique(a[,2])[2]," y ",unique(a[,2])[3],sep=""))
      } else if (length(unique(a[,2]))>1){
        sex<-tolower(paste(unique(a[,2])[1]," y ",unique(a[,2])[2],sep=""))
      } else {
        sex<-tolower(unique(a[,2]))
      }
      p<- plot_ly(data= b, x=~b[,1], y=~as.numeric(b[,4]), type = "box",name = "España",showlegend=FALSE) %>%
        layout(boxmode = "group",
               yaxis = list(title = unique(b[,5]),
                            titlefont = list(size = 10)),
               xaxis = list(title = 'Años', tickangle = -42,autotick = T), margin=list(b = -0.1), 
               legend = list(title=list(text='<b> Zonas (medianas) </b>'),
                             font=list(size=8))) %>%
        layout(title = list(text = HTML(paste0(paste('Evolución temporal segun',sex),
                                               '<br>',
                                               '<sup>',
                                               input$ind_1,
                                               '</sup>')),
                            font=list(size=14)),
               x=0,
               margin=list(t = 75)) %>%
        layout(
          showlegend = T) %>%
        add_annotations(
          text = "Fuente: Atlas de los determinantes sociales de la salud en España",
          legendtitle=TRUE,
          x = 0,
          y = -0.33,
          xref="paper",
          yref = "paper",
          align='left',
          textposition="bottom left",
          showarrow = FALSE,
          font = list(size = 9))
      p  %>%
        layout(resposnive = T)
    })
  }, ignoreInit = T)

} 

ui <-dashboardBody(
  fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "ind_1", 
      label = "Elige un indicador:", 
      choices = list_ind,
      selected=1),
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "ind_1_zona_1",
      label = "Selecciona la zona a estudiar:",
      choices = c("hola"),
      selected = 2,
      multiple = T),
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "ind_1_dim_1", 
      label = "hola", 
      choices = c("hola")),
  pickerInput(
    inputId = "ind_1_any_1",
    label = "Selecciona el periodo a estudiar:",
    choices = c("hola"),
    multiple = T),
  plotlyOutput("dots_box")
        )
      )
    )
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting reactives is not a good idea. You can control when the plot gets updated using `eventReactive()`.  Try this

```
 myplot <- eventReactive(c(input$ind_1_zona_1,input$ind_1_dim_1,input$ind_1_any_1), {  ## removed input$ind_1 so that it does not update when ind_1 is changed
  #observeEvent(c(input$ind_1,input$ind_1_zona_1,input$ind_1_dim_1,input$ind_1_any_1),{
    ############# FER 3 FILTRES DIFERENTS PER CADA PLOT #############
    #output$dots_box<-renderPlotly({
      a_<-subset(metadatos, metadatos[,5] %in% input$ind_1)
      a_id<-subset(indicadores_id,indicadores_id[,1]==a_[,4])
      a_id<-data.frame(indicadores[,1],
                       indicadores[,2],
                       indicadores[,3],
                       as.numeric(indicadores[,as.numeric(a_id[,2])]),
                       a_[,6])
      names(a_id)<-c("Periodo","Sexo","Zonas","Valor","Dim")
      a_id<-subset(a_id,!is.na(Valor))
      n<-input$ind_1
      a<-subset(a_id,a_id[,2] %in% input$ind_1_dim_1)
      a<-subset(a,a[,1] %in% input$ind_1_any_1)
      b<-subset(a,a[,3]!="ESPAÑA")
      a<-subset(a,a[,3] %in% input$ind_1_zona_1)
      if (length(unique(a[,2]))>2){
        sex<-tolower(paste(unique(a[,2])[1]," , ",unique(a[,2])[2]," y ",unique(a[,2])[3],sep=""))
      } else if (length(unique(a[,2]))>1){
        sex<-tolower(paste(unique(a[,2])[1]," y ",unique(a[,2])[2],sep=""))
      } else {
        sex<-tolower(unique(a[,2]))
      }
      p<- plot_ly(data= b, x=~b[,1], y=~as.numeric(b[,4]), type = "box",name = "España",showlegend=FALSE) %>%
        layout(boxmode = "group",
               yaxis = list(title = unique(b[,5]),
                            titlefont = list(size = 10)),
               xaxis = list(title = 'Años', tickangle = -42,autotick = T), margin=list(b = -0.1), 
               legend = list(title=list(text='<b> Zonas (medianas) </b>'),
                             font=list(size=8))) %>%
        layout(title = list(text = HTML(paste0(paste('Evolución temporal segun',sex),
                                               '<br>',
                                               '<sup>',
                                               input$ind_1,
                                               '</sup>')),
                            font=list(size=14)),
               x=0,
               margin=list(t = 75)) %>%
        layout(
          showlegend = T) %>%
        add_annotations(
          text = "Fuente: Atlas de los determinantes sociales de la salud en España",
          legendtitle=TRUE,
          x = 0,
          y = -0.33,
          xref="paper",
          yref = "paper",
          align='left',
          textposition="bottom left",
          showarrow = FALSE,
          font = list(size = 9))
      p  %>%  layout(responsive = T)
    #})
  #}, ignoreInit = T)
  })
  
  output$dots_box<-renderPlotly({
    myplot()
  })
```

Comment: Please write your comments in the comment below the answer. Then it will show me that someone responded to my answer. Also, please delete your answer below as it is a question.

Comment: My suggestion is to update the plot only after clicking on a action button.  This gives the user a chance to update whatever parameters they want, and then click on a button to display the updated plot.